# Validation errormessages not being displayed in the view with CakePHP 2.x

Tags: php, forms, validation, cakephp

I have scouted the internet and Stack Overflow for my problem, but nothing seems to work. That's why i'm creating this question.

I created a form in CakePHP, but as soon as i click the submit button and there are errors in the validation, i only see the error `$this->Flash->error(__('Not all fields are filled in.'));` creates in the view. 
All the inputted data has been deleted and i don't see the validation errors from the input fields.

If i'm not correct, the save function should generate the errors in the view.

What can be the reason the validation breaks?

This is my CustomerModel:

```
class Respondent extends AppModel {
    public $validate = array(
    'customer_id' => array(
        'numeric' => array(
            'rule' => array('numeric'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'user_id' => array(
        'numeric' => array(
            'rule' => array('numeric'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'accept_invitation' => array(
        'notBlank' => array(
            'rule' => array('notBlank'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            'required' => true,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'gender' => array(
        'notBlank' => array(
            'rule' => array('notBlank'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'first_name' => array(
        'alphaNumeric' => array(
            'rule' => 'alphaNumeric',
            'required' => true,
            'message' => 'Letters and numbers only'
        ),
        'notBlank' => array(
            'rule' => array('notBlank'),
            'message' => ': No first name',
            'allowEmpty' => false,
            'required' => true,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'middle_name' => array(
        'alphaNumeric' => array(
            'rule' => 'alphaNumeric',
            'required' => false,
            'message' => 'Letters and numbers only'
        ),
        'notBlank' => array(
            'rule' => array('notBlank'),
            //'message' => ': custom message',
            'allowEmpty' => true,
            'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'last_name' => array(
        'alphaNumeric' => array(
            'rule' => 'alphaNumeric',
            'required' => true,
            'message' => 'Letters and numbers only'
        ),
        'notBlank' => array(
            'rule' => array('notBlank'),
            'message' => ': : No last name',
            'allowEmpty' => false,
            'required' => true,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
);
}

// The Associations below have been created with all possible keys, those that are not needed can be removed


public $hasOne = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
}
```

My customerController:

```
public function register() {

    $userid = $this->Session->read('id');
    $user = $this->findByUserId($userid);
    debug($user);

    if(isset($user['Customer']['is_logged']) && $user['Customer']['is_logged']=== true ) {
        if ($user['Customer']['accept_invitation'] === 0) {
            $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'customers','action' => 'notaccepted'));
        } else {
            $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'customers','action' => 'accepted'));
        }
    }
    //set var
    $this->set(compact('userid'));

}

public function save() {
    //save data from user in db
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Customer->create();

        if ($this->Customer->save($this->request->data)) {

            if ($this->data['Customer']['accept_invitation'] == 0 ) {

                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'no'));
            } else {

                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'yes'));
            }
            $this->Flash->success(__('The customer has been saved.'));
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('Not all fields are filled in.'));

            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'register'));

        }
    }

}
```

My register.ctp view:

```
<div class="container">
<?php debug ($_SESSION); ?>

<?php print $this->Form->create('Customer', array('url' => 'save'));?>
<div class="col-md-12 ml15">
    <?php
    $useroptions = [
        '1' => 'Yes',
        '0' => 'No' ];
    $attributes = array(
        'legend' => false,
        'label' => array(
            'class' => 'p10'
        )
    );
    echo $this->Form->radio('accept_invitation', $useroptions, $attributes);
    ?>
</div>
<div  id="registerForm">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h2>Persoonlijke gegevens</h2>
        <?php echo $this->Form->hidden('user_id', array('value' =>  $userid )); ?>
        <?php echo $this->Form->hidden('is_logged', array('value' =>  1)); ?>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 ml15">
                <?php
                $options = array(
                    'm' => 'Mister',
                    'f' => 'Miss'
                );
                $attributes = array(
                    'legend' => false,
                    'label' => array(
                        'class' => 'p10'
                    )
                );
                echo $this->Form->radio('gender', $options, $attributes);
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('first_name', array(
                'div' => 'col-md-12 form-group',
                'label' => false,
                'class' => 'form-control',
                'placeholder' => 'First Name *'
            )
        );
        ?>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('middle_name', array(
                'div' => 'col-md-12 form-group',
                'label' => false,
                'class' => 'form-control',
                'placeholder' => 'Middle Name',
                'length' => 8,
                'required' => false
            )
        );
        ?>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('last_name', array(
                'div' => 'col-md-12 form-group',
                'label' => false,
                'class' => 'form-control',
                'placeholder' => 'Last Name *'
            )
        );
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <?php echo $this->Form->end('Send'); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not redirect in case validation error occurs. Check if data is valid by writing

```
if($this->Model->validates()){
     //save
}else{
     // set error in flash and do not redirect, let the view rendered. It will show error
}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. It worked. I thought it was possible to use a custom public function to handle the post request, but you were right. I just needed to place the logic from the save function in the register function. 
Now it works like a charm. Damn i feel noob :D

Thx again for pointin me in the right direction!